# Posgresql create table use information_schema

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm facing this problem, I created a database with multiple schemas other than public. When I connect with postgres user role (using pgAdmin, if I execute a create table statement, the table is not created but if I browse information_schema.tables that table is listed as table_schema=information_schema, even if in create statement I qualify the table with public schema. After that, if I create another table that reference the first one or just select from that table, postgres complains that the relation does not exixts. Then I have to drop the table to procede anyway. 
If I connect with another user role, that have superuser property set, the table is created in public schema.
Is there any database property that I have to set or something other I have to do to avoid the above problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try creating tables with mentioning schema name like (create table schemaname.tablename(...)) may be it solve your problem.

Comment: When in my question I said; "even if in create statement I qualify the table with public schema", I meant "create table public.tablename...."

Answer (score -1):

May be you type

```
set search_path = information_schema;
```

to make some queries in the information_schema. But when you create the table, it was created in the information_schema. That was because the first schema name in `set search_path` is the default for creating objects.

Comment: No, for sure. It happens only for some users including postgres, for other users I can query information_schema and create tables in public schema succesfully. I didn't find any preference to set serch_path by user role.